# implement non-blocking calls in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, asynchronous, nonblocking

I want to implement a non blocking call from a main thread to a shell script (which basically invokes an installation kinds and writes the progress of installation to some status file) and then keep do following 2 things in parallel in the main thread
1.keep checking the exit status of the script 
2.and simultaneously keep checking the progress of installation via the status file (which invoked the script)

How can i implement this kind of code in python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by using something like

```
pipe=Popen(["/bin/sh","-c","python /home/pkandpal/pkandpal/scriptTestStatusWriterTestModule.py > /dev/null 2>&1"])
```

where i can execute any script  as a child process
within a shell and keep a poll on the exit status using `pipe.poll()` which initially is null when the process is executing and is set to exit status after the script terminates successfully or unsuccessfully